# If $f(\langle x,y\rangle) = \langle y,x\rangle$, then prove $f$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $f(\langle x,y\rangle) = \langle y,x\rangle$ where  $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Well, my problem is intuitively I see a function that takes a pair of $(x,y)$ and gives another pair as $(y,x)$. so to me it seems the points are disconnected. Since this is one of Goldbergs book's excersices, I am definately wrong! I have studied several continuity questions for metric spaces, in which all functions's outputs were a value not a pair of $(y,x)$.

I will appreciate any explanation or hint on what is the point of this question.

Comment: Continuous is defined how, using $\epsilon, \delta$?  So write this down.  Here you can choose $\delta=\epsilon$.

Comment: Does $\langle x,y\rangle$ mean the same thing as $(x,y)$?

Comment: $f$ is in fact a linear transformation $f(v) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1& 0 \end{bmatrix} v$. Hence, it must be continuous.

Answer (score 3):

The input and output being disconnected is not what defines continuity ; what's important is there being "no sudden jump" when we change the input, or more formally that the limit of the function at a given point is defined and equal to the value of the function. We can easily show that for a fixed $\vec{v}$, $d(\vec{x}, \vec{v}) < \varepsilon \implies d(f(\vec{x}), f(\vec{v})) < \varepsilon$, which is the definition of continuity in metric spaces. $\langle \cdot \rangle$ is also uniformly continuous and $1$-lipschitz continuous.

Comment: Thank you very much. "Sudden Jump" , helped a lot.

Comment: Also note that geometrically $(x,y)\mapsto (y,x)$ is just the reflection through the diagonal line $x=y$, and as such, preserves distance, and consequently is (uniformly) continuous.